# What lvds connector do I have

Tags: lcd, touchscreen, lvds, monitor

Can someone help me find out what type of LVDS cable I have and point me in the direction of an adaptor to HDMI.
Thanks.

Backstory:
I recently had to throw out an old Sony Vaio All in one PC and decided to take out the monitor as it was nice and also touchscreen.
After searching around for adapters from LVDS to HDMI I realised the ports on the internet were different from the ones I have.
Searching for the model and other things didn't seem to come up with anything.
Here's some pictures:
[image: - the Cable]

And the original port on the old motherboard:
[image: Old mobo]

The monitor also has a few other cables which would be handy for someone to explain thier uses and what they are.
[image: other connectors]
I realise I'm asking a lot but if anyone knows anything please reply,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Those 2 pin cables on R and L actually go to an inverter board that was likely screwed to the AIO PC chassis, right beside mb. I did the same thing, however mine has a video card to the lvds ribbon cable and an HDMI out port also. About to hook it up and turn it on now actually.

Answer (score -2):

The left 2 pairs and the right 2 pairs go to CCFL tubes.

Comment: and just to save others the trouble of googling, CCFL = cold cathode fluorescent lamp

Comment: Or, in other words, the backlight.

Comment: @Albert  it is a good idea to edit those comments in to your answer.